# Field Id of a standard field

Tags: salesforce-id, custom-button

I am trying to populate couple of fields on `Contact` object one of them being `Contact Owner`. How can I find the Field Id of `Contact Owner` field?

Comment: you trying to populate it from APex?

Comment: I have a button which redirect them to Contact's edit page and in that page. The button url will be sending couple of parameters one of which will be the user Id going into Contact Owner filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Apex Code, take a look at the [SOAP API Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm), under Reference > Standard Objects. For custom buttons, you'll have to view the page source. Note that the `Contact Owner` field requires using the Transfer Ownership page instead of the normal edit page.

Comment: Is there a workaround to skip the Transfer Ownership page apart for writing a trigger which updates the Contact Owner with the values when certain conditions are met?

Comment: The standard UI doesn't allow editing the owner on the edit page, so if that's your goal, you'd want to use a trigger.

Comment: In fact, if I recall correctly, in earlier versions of salesforce.com, you couldn't change `OwnerId` and any other field in the same update even through the API.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, will create a trigger to capture the required values.